# wpdb update query not working

Tags: mysql, sql-update, wordpress

I've made an email script that should update as soon as wp_mail has result. For some reason my value won't update. Have I missed something? I am receiving the mail so the wp_mail works.

Cheers!

```
$email_result = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

if( $email_result ){//wp_mail() processed the request successfully
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpsc_coupon_codes";
    $coupon_id = $ereminder->ID;

$ereminders = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("
    UPDATE *
    FROM $table_name
    SET reminder = 1
    WHERE ID = $coupon_id
") );

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
UPDATE  $table_name
SET reminer = 1
WHERE ID = $coupon_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's still not working though (and I've changed the typo haha, reminer = reminder)

Comment: then check `$table_name` and `$coupon_id` if they gives right values

Comment: Error:  Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in

Answer (score 26):

Try This:

```
$wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'reminder' => 1),array('ID'=>$coupon_id));
```

Comment: Please help me understand how one can use multiple where format. LIke `WHERE ID='some_id' AND ( email='som email' OR username='some username')`

Answer (score 5):

We could use `$wpdb->update`, like this:

```
 global $wpdb;
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'your_table_name';
 $data_update = array('row_name_1' => $row_data_1 ,'row_name_2' => $row_data_2);
 $data_where = array('row_name' => $row_data);
 $wpdb->update($table_name , $data_update, $data_where);
```

Answer (score 4):

You may change instead of (UPDATE * FROM)

```
$ereminders = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET reminer='1' WHERE ID=$coupon_id"));
```

and use no break.

Thank you.

Comment: It will produce PHP warnings as `$wpdb->prepare` doesn't has any placeholder.

Correct code will be like this: `$ereminders = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET reminer='1' WHERE ID=%d", $coupon_id));
`

Answer (score 3):

Example of mine that is working:

```
$result = $wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->prefix .'sae_calendar', 
    array( 
        'year' => $year,
        'quarter' => $quarter,
        'start_date' => $start_date,
        'end_date' => $end_date,
        'reservation_start_date' => $reservation_start_date,
        'reservation_end_date' => $reservation_end_date 
    ), 
    array(
        "id" => $id
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['progress'])){
    $table=t_test;
    $data=array('client_development'=>$_POST['Progress']);
    $where=array('p_id'=>$_SESSION['id']);
    $format=("%d");
    $whereFormat=("%d");
    $result4=$wpdb->UPDATE($table,$data,$where,$format,$whereFormat);
  }
?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="Progress">
  <input type="submit" name="progress" value="Prog%">
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['progress'])){
$table=t_test;
    $data=array('client_development'=>$_POST['Progress']);
    $where=array('p_id'=>$_SESSION['id']);
    $format=("%d");
    $whereFormat=("%d");
    $result4=$wpdb->UPDATE($table,$data,$where,$format,$whereFormat);
}
?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="Progress">
  <input type="submit" name="progress" value="Prog%">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provides a function to update data of tables. You can also check [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/)

***wpdb::update( string $table, array $data, array $where, string[]|string $format = null, string[]|string $where_format = null ): int|false***

Example:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update($table,$data,$where);
```

**$table :** The table name.

**$data  :** A PHP array where the keys are the columns and the values are the the values to be inserted into those columns.

**$where :** A PHP array where the key is the column name, and the value is the value to be checked.